# Dynamically add input type select with options generate by api

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hello I try to generate a decision tree when the user chooses a reason option that generates the reasons and we create a select, if he clicks on an option and the API does not return an empty array another select below with sub-reasons which is created all this is dynamically created according to the response of the API as long as it does not return an empty array and so on

```
<template>
// the first select option don't generate 
           <select v-model="reasonOne" @change="eventOne(reasonOne)">
              <option
                v-for="(reason, key) in reasonsOne"
                :key="key"
                :value="reason.value"
                :selected="reason.item === reasonOne"
                @click="eventOne(reason.item)"
              >
                {{ reason.item }}
              </option>
            </select>

// the div with generate dynamically all select option
         <div v-if="showSav">
            <div id="select-pattern" class="step-two__select-wrapper" />
          </div>
<template/>

<script>
  async eventOne(option) {
    let reasonsReturn = await customerApi.getReturnPattern(
          app,
          this.detailReturn.sku.product.id
        );
        if (!this.reasonsReturn.length) {
          this.showSav = false;
        }
        let selectPattern = document.createElement('select');
        let target = document.getElementById('select-pattern');
        selectPattern.className = 'select-create';
        selectPattern.id = 'create-input';
        target.appendChild(selectPattern);
        for (let item of reasonsReturn) {
          let optionPattern = document.createElement('option');
          optionPattern.value = item.id;
          optionPattern.text = item.name;
          selectPattern.appendChild(optionPattern);
        }
        document
          .getElementById('create-input')
          .addEventListener('change', async function () {
            let reasonData = await customerApi.getReturnPattern(
              app,
              this.value
            );
          });
}
</script>
```

I was able to create the first select with it but the rest I am stuck I think we have to make a loop on select which will be created if the API returns data. i don't know how to do it while calling the api every time when the option changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create something dynamically the easiest way is to use a `v-for`. I could not reproduce your code, but I can show you how the structure is looking:

*TEMPLATE:*

Just use a `v-for` and loop over it for every `input` you will create (here it's created after clicking on a button)

```
<div v-for="item in inputs" :key="item.id">
  <!-- HERE YOU CAN PUT YOUR SELECTION -->
</div>
<b-button @click="addNewInput()">Add new Input</b-button>
```

*SCRIPT:*

Two things to do in your script. First: Define your data and create first `input` and than add a method for your `click-event` and `push` a input every time clicking on the button.

```
data() {
  return {
    id: 1,
    //following is your first input
    inputs: [{
      id: this.id += 1,   //count 1 for every input -> ID IS UNIQUE
    }]
  }
},

methods: {
  addNewInput() {
    this.inputs.push({
      id: this.id += 1
    })
  }
}
```

That's the structe you can do it with a `click-event` or with a `for-loop` inside of your methods but the structer stays always the same!

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: thanks Boby but i want to crate a select input when to click the option selected